# get different page-templates on one single page inside the loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress

EDIT: 
well, i can't handle it with `is_page` condition. so i wrote this following code - works well but it is not very nice. any suggestions?

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page' );?>  <!-- get only pages -->

<?php query_posts($args); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  <!-- loop with pages starts -->

<?php $id = get_the_ID(); ?>  <!-- get post/pageID --> 

<?php   if ($id == 5) : include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/page_special.php' );

        else: include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/page_all.php' );

        endif; 
?>
```

> i'm trying to make a wordpress theme with an one-page-layout. 
>   Therefor i edited my page.php into this, to get the different titles &
>   contents of the pages
>
> ```
> <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page' ); ?>
> <?php query_posts($args); ?>
> <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
>
> <section id="<?php the_title(); ?>">
>
> <header class="entry-header">
> <h1 class="entry-title"><a name="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>&nbsp;</h1>
> </header> 
> <div class="entry-content"> <?php the_content(); ?> </div>
>
> </section>
>
> <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
> ```
>
> Now i wanted to insert the if condition
>
> `is_page ('about') -> get_page_template ('about')`
>
> or something like that but Wordpress Codex says, that inside a loop
>   the `"is_page"` tag does not work.
>
> I don't want to write all my different section-templates in one and
>   the same page-template. Is there a way to call different
>   page-templates when you are on a page, yet?

Comment: if... then... else...

Comment: well, thx denix. that was exactly what i was lookin for.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_page( 'about' ) ) {

    $page_template =  dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/about_template.php';
}
```

This should work.

Comment: thanks sisyphus, but in my case, that doesn't work.
Wordpress Codex says:
"Due to certain global variables being overwritten during The Loop is_page() will not work. In order to use it after The Loop you must call wp_reset_query() after The Loop."

Comment: yes. if you use query($args) to get posts, then you should use wp_reset_query() at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) function, in your theme's `functions.php` file, e.g.:

```
function so16377966_template_redirect()
{
    if( is_page( 'about' ) )
    {
        include( get_template_directory() . '/about_template.php' );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so16377966_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Thank you diggy. But i think you got me wrong. 
The whole website is a one-single-page website. 
Menu is linking to #page2 #page3 etc. 

So the way around with the template_redirect function and its is_page('about') condition doesnt work because we'll never enter the page 'about' directly. do you know what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this inside the loop

```
<?php 
 // get the permalink that is http://www.somesite.com/about/
 $page = get_permalink();
     // extract will give you this Array ( [dirname] => http://www.somesite.com/about [basename] => about [filename] => about )
 extract(pathinfo($page));
// now you can use $filename to test if you are in the right page   
if ($filename == 'about') {
$page_template =  dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/about_template.php';
}
   ?>
```

how extract works 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php